# iPhone 13 and missing features on Instagram

Tags: iphone, instagram

**Issue**
On my iPhone 13 Pro, I do not have the same features available as on my friend's iPhone 13 Pro.

For example, in Stories, I cannot post location and tap a few times on it to change it to black background and white text. While I can tap and change some designs I do not have that particular one.

Also, the layout of things does differ. When I open to add text to a story at the bottom I do not have @mention and Location tabs

**What I tried**

1. Reinstalled Instagram several times - still no changes
2. Tried to log on from my friend's phone to my profile - Yes, I got the feature
3. Checked the app versions - yes, we do have the same
4. Wrote to Instagram support - no answer
5. Checked on older iPhone 11 - it has this feature

What other things I could try??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be for several reasons:

1. It is a common practice in software development to do [Controlled Roll-Outs](https://www.split.io/glossary/controlled-rollout/). This technique is used to release a new feature slowly for being able to monitor the usage in order to prevent failures or being able to release a new version if any bug is caught.
2. There's also another common practice called [A/B Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) which consist in giving the same feature to two users but with a different interface. With this technique, the company can extract data of which version works better or gets more interacted.
3. It is also known that Instagram gives some features based on the number of followers you have. For example, [this was happening with links in stories until they liberated the feature last year](https://about.instagram.com/blog/announcements/expanding-sharing-links-in-stories-to-everyone/).

So the summary is that I don't think you could do anything about it. For what you're saying it could be one of the three reasons.